# How do I remove a host-only adapter so I can continue with starting up the Docker Quickstart Terminal?

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I used [this guide](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/) to start installing Docker Toolbox. For step 3.2 I launch the Docker Quickstart Terminal. The first time I ran this a lot of progress info and status messaging was being displayed which I did not save unfortunately. In any case I believe the last message it showed is what I have pasted below. I am not sure. What I know for sure is that every time I try to start the Docker Quickstart Terminal, I see the error message below.

```
Starting "default"...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
Error setting up host only network on machine start: VirtualBox is configured with multiple host-only
adapters with the same name "HostInterfaceNetworking-Npcap Loopback Adapter". Please remove one
Looks like something went wrong in step ´Checking status on default´... Press any key to continue...
```

I do not understand how to get around it but I assume it has to do with me removing a host-only adapter. Any ideas how I should go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

i solved mine by uninstalling the previous virtual box and installing a new or latest version.